# How to invert the indices of a v-for with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array that I named "names", which is initially empty

```
names: []
```

I'm including elements in this array with the `unshift()` function, to always include elements at the beginning of the array and not at the end of it, so I do it like this:

```
names.unshift("Leonardo")
names.unshift("Victor")
names.unshift("Guilherme")
```

I'll use v-for to display the array elements on my page as a list:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="name in names">
     {{ name }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

The output will be:

- Guilherme
- Victor
- Leonardo

Now I want to list them with an index, so I do the following:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="(name, i) in names">
     {{ i }}: {{ name }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

and the output will be

- 1: Guilherme
- 2: Victor
- 3: Leonardo

But I want the indexes to be inverted, that is, that I have the following result:

- 3: Guilherme
- 2: Victor
- 1: Leonardo

How do I reverse the order of v-for indexes?

Comment: Could you use an [`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) with the [`reversed` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#attr-reversed) instead of a `<ul>` ([simple demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vd34xfz1/))?

Comment: Tried `names.length - i`?

Comment: <ol> with the reserved does not work with v-for @DavidThomas

Comment: `reversed`, @Victor, *not* `reserved`, and it works perfectly well so long as you allow the `<li>` elements to show their list-markers instead of relying on inserting the counter yourself. But if you need to do it that way, then obviously you have your answer now.

Comment: Yes @DavidThomas, I used the correct term, I just typed it wrong, did not work with unshift()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a little math to get the reversed index each loop:

```html
<ul>
   <li v-for="(name, i) in names">
     {{ names.length - i }}: {{ name }}
   </li>
</ul>
```